# Coloring DT columns

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to color "Emails" column below (Red if "Emails" is greater than "Calls", or else, its yellow). The challenge here is , can we also hide "Calls" column as well.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

x <- tibble(
  Unit = c("Sales", "Marketing", "HR"), 
  Calls = c(100, 150, 120), 
  Emails = c(200, 220, 230), 
  Calls_goal = c(1, 0, 0), 
  Emails_goal = c(0, 1, 1)
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    # Can't use both visible = FALSE and rownames = FALSE
    
    datatable(x,
              rownames = TRUE)
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

I've created an extra column called `diff` where we subtract the difference between the Calls and Emails, we shall use this column to do the coloring. Then we we can hide it along with the Calls column as per your request to the users using the `columnDefs` functionality. For the actual coloring, we can use `formatStyle` which has been documented well already https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

data <- tibble(
    Unit = c("Sales", "Marketing", "HR"), 
    Calls = c(100, 150, 120), 
    Emails = c(200, 220, 230), 
    Calls_goal = c(1, 0, 0), 
    Emails_goal = c(0, 1, 1)
)
data$diff <- data$Emails - data$Calls

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(data,
                  options = list(
                      columnDefs=list(
                          list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(1,5))
                      )
                  ),rownames = F)%>% 
            formatStyle("Emails",valueColumns = 'diff',BackgroundColor = styleInterval(c(0), c("Yellow",'Red')))
        
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]